# Dependencies aren't added to package.json file

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, visual-studio-code

I am building a MEAN stack application using **vscode** editor. I installed some **packages** with npm, but **package.json** doesn't add them my project configuration.

Answer (score 3):

you probably forgot to add the --save flag to your npm install

```
npm install PACKAGE_NAME --save
```

will add it to the dependencies in your package.json. If you use --save-dev, it will add them to dev dependencies instead

Comment: Yes, i did add --save flag, but package.json file still doesn't add those packages.